# undefined sequence for the "list of figures" due to the labels defined in my Tikz plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I got a number of Tikz plots that I include in my LaTeX source. Those Tikz plots contain `\label{labelnamel}` which I then use in the caption of my figure:

```
 \begin{figure} 
 \input{Figs/tikzplot.tex}
 \caption{plot a \ref{labenameA}. plot b \ref{labelnameB} }
 \end{figure}
```

Now when my LaTeX project tries to make a List of Figures, the error comes up:

I get the error that it has undefined sequence (`\pgfplots@show@ref@labelnameA`) and it directly refers to the those `\ref` that corresponds to the labels in my Tikz. I can see from my PDF file that the table fails to understand what that reference is.
I do even have `\cite` sometimes in my caption and that *works* perfectly for list of figures.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
% Some useful packages for including images, colored font, etc.
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}


\RequirePackage{natbib}
% Global bibliography style


% Set margins in all document to 3.5cm as per guidelines for binding
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\linespread{1.3}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
% Center on all pages
\fancyhead[C]{---Draft---}
% Page number placed on right side on odd pages and left side on even pages
\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\thepage}
\usepackage{amsmath} % required by declare math operator
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} %Referencing without need to explicitly state fig /table
% TIKZ
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\fheight
\newlength\fwidth 
%to color a row by using \rowcolor{gray}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
%define light gray
\definecolor{lightGray}{gray}{0.9}
%% language algo
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
% Set page numbers to roman numerals for front matter
\pagenumbering{roman}
% Include a list of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
% Set page numbering to arabic for body of Thesis
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% For example
\chapter{Test}
\begin{figure}[t] 
    \setlength\fheight{0.5\columnwidth}
    \setlength\fwidth{0.4\columnwidth}
    \centering
    %   
    \input{nitvali_all}
    %   
    %
    \caption{
        (\ref{ref1}) reef1
        (\ref{ref2}) reef2}
    \label{fig:validation}
    %
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

The Tikz file `nitvali_all.tex`:

```
% This file was created by tikzplotlib v0.9.1.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 1}]

\nextgroupplot[
height=\fheight,
%legend cell align={left},
%legend columns=4,
%legend style={fill opacity=0.8, draw opacity=1, text opacity=1, draw=white!80!black,at={(-1, 1.10)}, anchor=north},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
title={(c): Case 3},
width=\fwidth,
x grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
xlabel={Time [ms]},
xmajorgrids,
xmin=0, xmax=8.2,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.0196078431373!black},
ymajorgrids,
ymin=0, ymax=12.8,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [semithick, black, mark=*, mark size=1.5, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
7.50304269790649 8.61112403869629
7.73022317886353 8.7830286026001
7.98580121994019 8.92600917816162
}; \label{ref1}
\addplot [semithick, black, mark=square*, mark size=1.5, mark options={solid}, only marks]
table {%
0.0701577663421631 0.345906138420105
0.106774091720581 0.548678278923035
0.216410160064697 0.89439582824707
};\label{ref2}
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example that give this problem but also allows others to copy your example and try it for themself.  You should of course make sure that your document compiles without any errors as errors have a tendency to accumulate and give strange results.

Comment: note @daleif means that your document should not have _other_ errors. It should of course show the error that you are asking about.

Comment: I put one. You need to compile at least three times ( at least for me) to sort out the reference in the caption and to get up the list of figures. Once the list of figures is generated you should see the errors

Comment: Any ideas, where you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: You need to use `\protect\ref{...}` in the caption.  Normally \ref is robust and doesn't need to be protected, but by the time it reaches the lof file it has become `\pgfplots@show@ref@ref`.